# How to use infoWindow.setFixedAnchor

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, infowindow

In the older versions of the ArcGIS JavaScript API, you could specify the position of the infoWindow using `map.infoWindow.setFixedAnchor(esri.dijit.InfoWindow.ANCHOR_UPPERRIGHT);`

In version 3.11 this fails with *TypeError: esri.dijit.InfoWindow is undefined*

The [help file](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/infowindow-amd.html#setfixedanchor) for version 3.11 now says that setFixedAnchor is a string, so I tried `map.infoWindow.setFixedAnchor("ANCHOR_UPPERRIGHT");` but this returns *TypeError: map.infoWindow.setFixedAnchor is not a function*

What is the correct syntax for using `setFixedAnchor` with an infoWindow in version 3.11 and above?

```
map.on("load", function(){
  map.infoWindow.resize(250,100); //this works
  map.infoWindow.setFixedAnchor("ANCHOR_UPPERRIGHT"); //this fails
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John said, `map.infoWindow` is an instance of `esri/dijit/Popup`, not `esri/dijit/InfoWindow` like it was many releases ago.

You can specify anchor directly:

```
map.infoWindow.anchor = "top";
```

Or use `set()`:

```
map.infoWindow.set("anchor", "top");
```

All valid values are listed in the [API ref for the popup's anchor property](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#anchor).

Comment: Thanks Derek. Does that mean that the entry at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/infowindow-amd.html#setfixedanchor needs to be removed or updated if that method has been deprecated?

Comment: the method hasn't been deprecated.  you're attempting to call it on an entirely different class (esri/dijit/Popup as opposed to esri/dijit/InfoWindow).  that being said the jsapi implementation of popups has always confused me, so i don't begrudge you yours :)

Answer (score 1):

the doc you linked to has information at the top about Popup now being assigned to the map by default.

Popup
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html

you could either go the route of trying to see whether it's possible to set the 'anchor' property on Popup or declare explicitly that you want esri.dijit.InfoWindow to be assigned instead.